# Need to use Update statement with dynamic sql in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I have a target table `dbo.val` with three columns: `table_schema`, `table_name` and `row_count`, with the schema and name already populated and respective row counts set to zero for a particular database.
I need row counts for each table name, but can't use system tables for row count as they might give inaccurate data at times.

I used a cursor to get table and schema name from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to get populated in `@tb_schema` and `@tb_table` variables and used a third variable `@c_name` to club both

```
set @c_name = @tb_schema + '.' + @tb_name;
```

I need an update stament to take dynamic count from `@c_name` and populate the `row_count` column of `dbo.val` which can later put in a loop
     This is what I tried but it didnt work:

```
 update dbo.val set row_count = Exec ('select COUNT(*) from ' + @full_name)
 where table_schema = @tb_schema and table_name =@tb_name  ;
```

I also tried the below, which didnt work as well

```
declare @catch numeric (20)
select @catch = Exec ('select COUNT(*) from ' + @full_name) ;
update dbo.validate set cnt = @catch
where tb_schema = @tb_schema and tb_name =@tb_name  ;
```

Can anyone help me out, as to how to update the row count of my target table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @full_name varchar(75)
DECLARE @row_count int

SET @full_name = @tb_schema + '.' + @tb_name; 
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM '+ @full_name 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@cnt int OUTPUT', @cnt=@row_count OUTPUT

update dbo.val 
set    row_count = @row_count 
where  table_schema = @tb_schema 
  and  table_name =@tb_name
```

Also you need to create cursor to fetch `@tb_schema` and `@tb_name` from dbo.val.

Comment: Do you need any help with cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `CURSOR` to do this. Here is how:

First, let's create our sample data.

```
--Table to UPDATE
CREATE TABLE validate(
    tb_schema   VARCHAR(256),
    tb_Name     VARCHAR(256),
    cnt         INT
)
INSERT INTO validate VALUES
('dbo', 'TableA', 0), ('dbo', 'TableB', 0);

--Sample TableA with 50 rows
CREATE TABLE TableA(id int);
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT TOP(50) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns a

--Sample TableB with 20 rows
CREATE TABLE TableB(id int);
INSERT INTO TableB
    SELECT TOP(20) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns a
```

And here is the solution using a temporary table:

```
--Temporary table to hold the row counts of each table
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    tb_schema   VARCHAR(256),
    tb_Name     VARCHAR(256),
    cnt         INT
)

--Generate your dynamic SQL here
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO #temp(tb_schema, tb_Name, cnt)' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql + 
'SELECT ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + ''', ''' + name + ''', COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name <> 'validate'

--Remove the last occurence of UNION ALL
SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11)

--Check the generated SQL
PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

--Update dbo.validate from values in #temp
UPDATE v
    SET cnt = t.cnt
FROM dbo.validate v
INNER JOIN #temp t
    ON t.tb_schema = v.tb_schema
    AND t.tb_name = v.tb_name

--Check result
SELECT * FROM validate
```

Comment: Thanks alot Felix ! I didnt thought it in this way !

Comment: No problem. Glad to have been of help.